# Как сделать сортировку по произвольному полю по убыванию и возрастанию?

Tags: php, wordpress

на сайте есть AJAX фильтр, после выдачи результата, нужно отсортировать на выбор: по категории(таксономия), по цене(кастомное поле ACF): возрастанию убыванию, и площади(так же как цена)

Как отсортировать по дате или заголовку я понял

```
<label><input type="radio" name="date" value="ASC" /> Дата: по возрастанию</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="date" value="DESC" /> Дата: по убыванию</label>
```

functions.php

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => $_POST['date']
);
```

Пробовал так

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'cost-per-metr', // id поля цена
        ),
       'orderby' => 'cost-per-metr',
       'order'  => $_POST['date']
    );
```

Но понятно не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так :

```
$args['meta_key'] = 'custom-field-slug';

$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';

$args['order'] = 'DESC'; //ASC
```

Официальные примеры https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/